# Receive file with request.files vs request.form in Flask

Tags: ajax, flask

I'm using `ajax` to send **file** via `POST` request to the server (my `Flask` app), but I can only retrieve this file (binary data) in `Flask` using `request.form`, not `request.files`, and `request.files` is desired. Code as below.

How can I get file with `request.files` ? (Conversely, with `Postman` and other tools, I can get the file with `request.files`. In `request.form` case, info such as `content-type` is missing)

```
// "file_content" is read previously

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file_content);  // "file_content" is binary data

.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  async: false,
  url: ...,
  data: formData,
  dataType:"json",
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
});
```

The tricky thing is send a local file, and most relevant answers are using document.getElementById().

Comment: please share with us the code of view function that handles the `POST` request to retrieve file. maybe this tutorial helps you https://pythonbasics.org/flask-upload-file/,  i guess you are inspiring code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax, also make sure to add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in your form